# How to Check the string is same or changed in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, nsstring

I check the frame of any subclass, if it is change or not with the following code.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if(imageFrameSize ==  CGRectZero) {
            imageFrameSize = self.recycleBin.frame;
            NSLog(@"Frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(imageFrameSize));
        }
}
```

Now I want to check the string is same or changed. Basically I am storing history in history.plist. And I run the function in below delegate to save document url in history.plist file.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    //when push to reload is done it will disappear pulltorefresh
    [(PullToRefreshView *)[self.view viewWithTag:998] finishedLoading];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    [self actualizeButtons];


   urlPage =[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];    //[[[webView request] URL]absoluteString];

   [self addHistoryFunction];


    NSLog(@"WebView Finish Load %@",[[[webView request] URL]absoluteString] );

}
```

This function works good. But the problem is that webViewDidiFinishLoad run almost two times for google and three or many times for other websites. So addHistoryFuncation save the history two or more times with same page url. 
I want to check the urlPage string before adding to history, if it is updated new string then run the addhistory function, if it is same then skip addhistory function.  Just like above CGRectZero code.

Thats my idea to save history in history.plist.
If there is a better then mine please help me or solve my issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`  called when ever awebview finish loading an object with in the web page so the best approch to prevent this method to be called more than once to add this line :

```
if ([webView isLoading]){return;)
```

this line will make sure that your webview will do the commands when its only finishedl loading.
here is your function after edit try it .

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
     if ([webView isLoading]){return;)
    //when push to reload is done it will disappear pulltorefresh
    [(PullToRefreshView *)[self.view viewWithTag:998] finishedLoading];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    [self actualizeButtons];


   urlPage =[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];    //[[[webView request] URL]absoluteString];

   [self addHistoryFunction];


    NSLog(@"WebView Finish Load %@",[[[webView request] URL]absoluteString] );

}
```

Comment: No.. still it runs NSLog(@"WebView Finnish Load... ); two times for google and more for other websites....

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compare to string this is how

```
BOOL isTheSameStrings=[mystring isEqualToString:string2];
if (isTheSameStrings){
   NSLog(@"the are the same);
}else{
   NSLog(@"the are NOT the same);
}
```

or you want to check if the string found in an array

```
BOOL myArrayDoesContainMyString=[myArray containsObject:myString];
if (myArrayDoesContainMyString){
   NSLog(@"myArray contain myString);
}else{
   NSLog(@"myArray does not contain myString);
}
```